# Android - getExternalCacheDirectory throws NullPointerException after being called from a static method

Tags: java, android, android-activity, static, nullpointerexception

I am writing my first Android application. I need to initialize a File in a non-static method with the path that is returned by `getExternalCacheDirectory()`. 
Here's the first part of the relevant code:

```
public static void deleteNote(Integer id) {
    List<Note> savedNotes = Util.getSavedNotes();
    savedNotes.remove(id);
    NoteRemover myRemover = new NoteRemover();
    myRemover.write(savedNotes, id);
}
```

Here's my `NoteRemover` class:

```
    public class NoteRemover extends Activity{
    public void write(List<Note> editedNotesList, Integer rnID) {

           //NullPointerExeption is thrown here:
            File notesDB = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), "notesDB.txt");

            String Data;

             //unimportant code

            Util.setFtpTaskFlag(2);
            Util.setFtpDirectory(Util.FTP_NOTE_DIR);
            Util.writeFile(data, notesDB);

            Util.setFtpTaskFlag(3);
            File note = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), rnID.toString()
                    + ".txt");
            Util.deleteFile(note);

            Util.setFtpTaskFlag(-1);
            Util.setFtpDirectory(null);'

        }

    }

}
```

Here's the Errormessage:

```
02-02 21:41:24.354: E/AndroidRuntime(6552): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-02 21:41:24.354: E/AndroidRuntime(6552): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-02 21:41:24.354: E/AndroidRuntime(6552):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getExternalCacheDir(ContextWrapper.java:219)
02-02 21:41:24.354: E/AndroidRuntime(6552):     at com.stracke.bandmanager.NoteRemover.write(NoteRemover.java:11)
02-02 21:41:24.354: E/AndroidRuntime(6552):     at com.stracke.bandmanager.Notes.deleteNote(Notes.java:131)
02-02 21:41:24.354: E/AndroidRuntime(6552):     at com.stracke.bandmanager.OptionsDialogFragment.doSelectedDialogAction(OptionsDialogFragment.java:52)
02-02 21:41:24.354: E/AndroidRuntime(6552):     at com.stracke.bandmanager.OptionsDialogFragment.access$0(OptionsDialogFragment.java:25)
02-02 21:41:24.354: E/AndroidRuntime(6552):     at com.stracke.bandmanager.OptionsDialogFragment$1.onClick(OptionsDialogFragment.java:18)
02-02 21:41:24.354: E/AndroidRuntime(6552):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:941)
02-02 21:41:24.354: E/AndroidRuntime(6552):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
02-02 21:41:24.354: E/AndroidRuntime(6552):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1102)
02-02 21:41:24.354: E/AndroidRuntime(6552):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2790)
02-02 21:41:24.354: E/AndroidRuntime(6552):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3465)
02-02 21:41:24.354: E/AndroidRuntime(6552):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-02 21:41:24.354: E/AndroidRuntime(6552):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-02 21:41:24.354: E/AndroidRuntime(6552):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-02 21:41:24.354: E/AndroidRuntime(6552):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5124)
02-02 21:41:24.354: E/AndroidRuntime(6552):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-02 21:41:24.354: E/AndroidRuntime(6552):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-02 21:41:24.354: E/AndroidRuntime(6552):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-02 21:41:24.354: E/AndroidRuntime(6552):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-02 21:41:24.354: E/AndroidRuntime(6552):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As far as I can see `getExternalCacheDirectory()` throws a NullPointerException. My guess is that the method is originally called from a static method and therefore throws the exceptions since I cannot call `getExternalCacheDirectory()` in a static method anyways.
Does anyone know how I can solve this problem? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How you are holding `myRemover` Activity in static method?

Comment: sorry but how do you mean that? (I'm still a beginner...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating `NoteRemover` like normal object but `NoteRemover` is an `Activity` (which is subclass of context). `Activities` should be created by system, because now this `myRemover` is just an object without any connection to the system.

Make your method in some utilities class:

```
class WriteUtils
{
    public static void write(List<Note> editedNotesList, Integer rnID, Context context)
    {
       File notesDB = new File(context.getExternalCacheDir(), "notesDB.txt");
       // and so on.. use context.get... 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it out as soon as possible.